# Why outputs differ between VScode python terminal & Interactive window?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, input, casting

I was runing this code on VScode :

```
a = input("a : ")
b = int(a) + 2
print(f"a:{a},b:{b}")
```

The output on **Python terminal**:

```
a : b = int(a) + 2
>>> print(f"a:{a},b:{b}")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'b' is not defined
```

The Output on **Interactive window** for **input 12** :

```
 a:12,b:14
```

What's the problem here ?

**P.S.** A similar terminal problem is in this thread but still without any solution.
[Why there are different outputs here?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71268484/16322761)

Comment: you didnt input 12 on the python terminal, you just started typing the next line of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for the help. What I found out from the answers is that Terminal & Interactive window behave different from each other.

**Terminal :** Executes line by line of code. So giving a block of code at once with input at first line of the block doesn't work well here.

**Interactive window :** Can take blocks of code & act/execute smarter than the Terminal as you can see in the output of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Add your full code in a file, save it. Hit f.e. F5 to debug/run program.

You may need to select

[image]

to run it. It will be executed in the "TERMINAL":

[image: input prompt]

input a number:

[image: 42 inputted]

hit enter:

[image: result]

---

If you take all your code into the copy/paste buffer and "paste" it into the interactive console it will be executed **line by line**.

Essentially you paste

```
a = input("a: ")
```

then it takes your next line

```
b = int(a) + 2
```

**as your input** and stores it inside `a`.

Then it executes

```
print(f"a:{a},b:{b}")
```

and complains about `b` because your line `b = int(a) + 2` was used as `input()`  and is now stored as string inside `a`.

Comment: I did this & it also showed the output if you execute the code line by line rather than running all at once like the interactive window . But why the terminal doesn't  behave like the Interactive window here ?

Comment: @Niloy  - see edit

Answer (score 0):

it is simple

if you write `a = input("a : ")` in python terminal it get execute see this [image]

Also If I copy your code and paste it into the terminal then it looks like this

[image]

-> If you see in this image here b = int(a) + 2 take as the input of a. Therefore you get error

> b is not defined

**Conclusion**

As you write `a = input("a : ")` you need to give the input here example(12)
then write `b = int(a) + 2`
And, Then `print(f"a:{a}:b{b}")`

Comment: There isn't really any point in answering a question the op could have solved themselves if they'd ran their code more than once. Would be better to just vote or flag to close it as unlikely to help future readers